# Python using system SSL certificates?

Tags: python, ssl, curl, authorize.net

I ran into the recent Authorize.net SSL certificate invalidation [debacle](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/SSL-certificate-problem-again/td-p/39858) last week.

I've been able to get curl to accept their certificate finally:

```
$ curl -Iv https://secure.authorize.net
...
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
...
```

but python is still rejecting it with requests:

```
>>> requests.get('https://secure.authorize.net', verify=True)
...
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

and in my code:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 405, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Can anyone tell me why python doesn't seem to be using the system certificates for validation? Any ideas on a fix?

**EDIT**

I am using Ubuntu and installed the certificate this way:

```
sudo curl -o /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/entrust_ssl_ca.crt https://www.entrust.net/downloads/binary/entrust_ssl_ca.cer
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

after running this, curl worked properly, but python still didn't recognize the certificate.

Answer (score 4):

You don't mention what OS you're using or where you installed the certificates to make them available to Curl.

I used `strace` on my system to see where Python is looking for certificates.  On my Fedora system Python is using`/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`, which is the standard location on Fedora, Red Hat, and similar systems.

On Ubuntu, Python is looking in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification):

> You can pass verify the path to a CA_BUNDLE file with certificates of
>   trusted CAs. This list of trusted CAs can also be specified through
>   the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable.

...so you could provide your application with a list of CA certificates that is independent of what is installed on the system.

**Update**

Running `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect secure.authorize.net:443` shows that the `*.authorize.net` certificate is signed by the "Entrust Certification Authority - L1K" certificate, which is signed by the "Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2" certificate, which is signed by the "Entrust Root Certification Authority" certificate.  The certificate you have installed as `entrust_ssl_ca.crt` is the "Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority", which is "none of the above".

I would just visit http://www.entrust.com/get-support/ssl-certificate-support/root-certificate-downloads/ and download everything, but the top-level certificate in the above chain is [this one](http://www.entrust.com/root-certificates/entrust_ev_ca.cer).  That's the second certificate listed on the downloads page.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question with the operating system details and how I installed the new certificate.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using python's SSL module, and not requests in my app's code. I was just using requests as a reproducible example.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the specific certificate I had to install in order to make Python happy, when starting with an empty certificates directory.